# machine learning algorithm with list of arrays as data set

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

i'm new in data science and i'm searching for machine learning algorithm that take data set as List of arrays each array have sequence of floats data

**A little bit of context**: we have some angels that took from user motion ,
by these angels we determines if the user make the correct motion or not ,
the motion represented in our system in list of array each array has sequence of angels 
any help please ? i searched for a lot of time but have no result !

Comment: This is waaaay too broad for stack overflow.  Also, if you don't have a basic understanding of machine learning, even if someone did try and make a stab at answering your question it wouldn't do you much good.  Also, you really shouldn't tag this as python since it has nothing to do with python.

Answer (score 1):

Check out neupy. It is a great library for new machine learning users. I would suggest just the standard back propagation algorithm with momentum. It has been proven that newer adaptive learning techniques don't do as well as the simple gradient back propagation algorithm with momentum.

It is easy to implement. It would be implemented for example using the following code,

## A: Create data set

```
x = np.zeros((len(list[0]),len(list)))
for i in np.arange(len(list)):
    for j in np.arange(len(list[0]):
        x[i][j] = list[i][j]
```

This would be the input. Then you create the architecture

## B: Create Architecture

```
network = layers.Input(len(list[0])) > layers.Sigmoid(int(len(list[0])/2)) > layers.Sigmoid(2)
```

## C: Use Gradient Descent With Momentum

```
gdnet = layers.Algorithms.Momentum(network,momentum=0.1)
gdnet.train(x,y, max_iter=1000)
```

Where y is the movement of interest.

## D: Predict Motion

```
y_predicted = gdnet(x)
```

Comment: You might have to check the shape of the input here.

Answer (score -1):

In general, most libraries take in numpy arrays as inputs. 
There are a number of ways to wrangle your data into that format. I find pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) to be the most convenient way. If you have the data in .csv file, excel sheet or some other common, structured format, pandas has functions for loading that in with no pain at all

If you give some more details (Are you using a machine learning library (like sci-kit), what format the data is in) i can be of more help.

Comment: we make application  for build muscles 
and we use Kinect  and we get some angles for every exercise 
we need to give this angles to  machine learning algorithm that will train